# Difficulty manipulating objects in XIB files.

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

I've discovered that once I've stacked too many layered views in an XIB file, it becomes really difficult to select and manipulate them. I'll usually start by selecting an object from the Objects list then drag it around to relocate it. In that process, a different view gets selected and the entire heirarchy gets thrown off whack.

Is there some way (such as in Adobe Illustrator), to only enable selection of one object (lock everything else) so you don't accidentally select them when dragging things around?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select objects in the tree view and then use arrow keys to move them around (or explicitly set the location)